# Are there any limitations on the functionality of PostGIS related to the version of PROJ?

Tags: postgis, proj

PROJ >= 7 optionally requires curl and libtiff. Are there any limitations on functionality of PostGIS if PROJ is not installed with them which are optional?

I would like to use all functionality of PostGIS. I am building PostGIS and reading the official document. I understand that PROJ >= 6 is required to use all the functions. Is this version 6 enough to use all? If I use PROJ >= 7, should I install PROJ with optional requirements?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't intend to work with gridded models, part of the improvements to make Proj "a full geodetic transformation and description environment" ([PROJ RFC 4: Remote access to grids and GeoTIFF grids](https://proj.org/community/rfc/rfc-4.html#rfc4)) then you could use the older Proj 6 or you could use Proj >= 7 and not include the curl and libtiff dependencies. From [Proj 7.0.0 Release Notes](https://proj.org/news.html#id434):

> The major feature in PROJ 7 is significantly improved handling of
> gridded models. This was implemented in PROJ RFC 4: Remote access to
> grids and GeoTIFF grids. The main features of the RFC4 work is that
> PROJ now implements a new grid format, Geodetic TIFF grids, for
> exchanging gridded transformation models. In addition to the new grid
> format, PROJ can now also access grids online using a data store in
> the cloud.
>
> ... snip ...
>
> The use of the new grid format and the data from the cloud requires
> that PROJ is build against libtiff and libcurl. Both are optional
> dependencies to PROJ but it is highly encouraged that the software is
> build against both.

I see no reference to gridded models in PostGIS documentation or issues. I expect the use of such transformations is hidden from PostGIS by the Proj library but I don't know that. If that is the case, then you would need to decide whether you are using projections that use those gridded model transformations.

There are undoubtedly other features and bug fixes in later Proj releases unrelated to the gridded models. I'd go with a current stable version, whether or not I thought I'd need the curl and libtiff dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand that current stable version 9.1.1 is recommended. Let me confirm one thing, are you installing this version with libtiff and curl? If I use new grid format, libtiff is required. But I don’t think curl is not necessary to util PostGIS functionalities.

Comment: It seems that network capability is disabled by default, even if Proj has been built with curl (https://proj.org/resource_files.html#proj-ini). As you wrote, gridded models require libtiff but you can use those without curl if you do not want Proj to retrieve the grid data from Content Delivery Networks (CDN) and are instead fine with manually downloading and installing the grid data (or installing the package that includes the grid data).

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your kind answer!!!!